# how to get the _id element from map-reduce collection

Tags: mongodb, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to get the value of the key `"_id"` of a collection created by a map-reduce operation.

I'm running the function `(fill-mr-template)` below to store the values generated from my map-reduce operation.

```
(defun fill-mr-template ()
  (let ( (found-mr (docs (db.find *mr-collection* :all))))
    (loop for i in found-mr collect
      (let ( (mr-object (make-instance 'mr
                :_id   (get-element "_id" i)
                    :value (get-element "value" i))))
        (list :_id (_id mr-object)
          :value (value mr-object))))))
```

The results for this in the REPL are:

```
((:_ID NIL :VALUE 30.0d0) (:_ID NIL :VALUE 20.0d0))
```

And my collection, at mongoDB is:

```
> db.*mr-collection*.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : "16 months", "value" : 30 }
{ "_id" : "18 months", "value" : 20 }
```

So, as you can see, my function `(fill-mr-template)` is getting the value from the `&key` `:value` but is getting `NIL` for the `&key` `:_id`.

Below, is the class 'mr that I'm using to create the object "mr-object" to store the values.

```
(defclass mr ()
  ( (_id   :accessor _id
       :initarg :_id)

    (value :accessor value
       :initarg :value)))
```

Can anyone help with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you building the `mr` object for some later purpose (ie is this code incomplete?  As it stands the object is almost immediately unreferenced.  As it is I think you need to sort out what `get-element` returns: pretty clearly the problem is there.

Comment: Can you extract the first element in found-mr and show what it contains, using INSPECT or DESCRIBE?

Comment: @tfb Indeed, the code is not complete. I use the object to pass the information to a html template and print it on a web application. I posted only the code section that I believe it's relevant for the problem. If you think it would be useful, I'll be gladly to post the full code for the function (fill-mr-template). Just let me know, please. Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, assuming you have evaluated everything (ie the definition of `mr` is what you think it is and there is not some complication around it), then `(_id (make-instance 'mr ... :_id (get-element "_id" i)))` is simply whatever `(get-element "_id" i)` returns, so you really need to check whatever that function returns.

Comment: @coredump Done! `The object is a STANDARD-OBJECT of type DOCUMENT. 0. ELEMENTS: #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 1 {10052E8E93}> 1. _LOCAL_ID: NIL 2. _ID: "16 months"'`

Comment: @tfb As far as I know, the `(get-element)` returns the document attribute that I choose. For example, when I have a document inside a collection named "MyCollection" in Mongodb with a attribute "test" and it's value is "123", if I do `(get-element "test" MyCollection)` it will return "123". I use this all over my code to get the attribute values from others collections, and it works fine. The reason why this is not working for the attribute "_id" is what I'm traying to find ;(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identifier is directly stored as a slot in the instance of `cl-mongo:document`. Other elements are stored in a hash-table, and can be retrieved with `get-element`; but the identifier most probably is accessed by calling [`cl-mongo:doc-id`](https://github.com/fons/cl-mongo#doc-id).

Comment: Dude, I'm in love with you. One week trying to find the answer, don't know how I didn't. Thank you sou much!!!